# GoogleMaps in UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, google-maps, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to open googlemaps using `UIActivityViewController`, I've searched and found that this code should work

```
@IBAction func showRestaurantOnMap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic")
    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [url!], applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = []

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but it doesn't, what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!) {
        print(1)
    }
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "yandexmaps://")!) {
        print(2)
    }
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/")!) {
        print(3)
    }
```

works prefect and return 1, 2 and 3

Comment: you getting any error ?

Comment: no, but I got message and mail apps and able to choose some more, but not google maps

Comment: Do you have GoogleMaps installed in your phone?

Comment: yeap, I am also trying with yandex maps, not working either

Comment: Did you define URL Schemes? refer this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Comment: I've added schemes to info.plist and check update in question